# Nontrivial circular arguments?

Tags: lo.logic, nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, foundations

There is a famous circular argument for the Prime Number Theorem (PNT).  It turns
out that there exists an infinite sequence of elementary-to-prove Chebyshev-type estimates
that taken together imply PNT.  Unfortunately, the *collective* existence of all these proofs seems to require the PNT, so one must work hard a la Selberg and Erdos for an elementary proof. See Harold Diamond, Elementary methods in the study of the distribution of prime numbers, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. N. S. 7 (1982), 553-589.

Now on the traditional view, circular proofs simply have no value at all.  Yet one feels perhaps that the example in the previous paragraph has something to say.  Just an illusion?  Or does there exist a foundational framework where circular proofs of this special sort enjoy bona fide status?

Just to riff a little more, imagine that the Goldbach conjecture turns out independent of PA (or some other, perhaps weaker, axiom system for arithmetic).  The truth of the Goldbach conjecture (required for independence!) would then imply the existence of a proof (trivial!) for any given even number that that one even number equals the sum of two primes.  Now that obviously isn't very interesting compared to the example in the first paragraph, and perhaps the difference has something to do with the greater quantifier complexity of PNT?

As a side question, are there any similar stories in the lore of the Riemann Hypothesis?
For example, does RH imply the existence of an infinite sequence of zero-free region proofs of a known form that collectively amount to RH?

---

EDIT:  Lest this come up repeatedly, let me expand upon a remark I made in a comment below:

I would be interested to know if RH implies the existence of proofs of a known form in a known system within which one does not assume RH, such that the conclusions of all these proofs conjunctively yield RH.

Actually the answer to my question is "yes" though I find my own example unsatisfying
(rather like the Goldbach example):

We can check zeros up to a given magnitude rigorously by known (non-trivial) numerical techniques.  RH predicts these tests will come out positive, but of course the tests
don't rely on RH.  If we know they all come out positive, that's RH.  I find this unsatisfying because the little proofs approximate the whole of RH so badly (compared to
how the Chebyshev estimates really do make one feel one has PNT for all practical purposes).  Now a family of zero-free regions that union up to $\sigma >1/2$ where each new zero-free region had strong arithmetic consequences, that would seem interesting.

Comment: Perhaps psychologically we feel that the infinite sequence of Chebyshev-type estimates could, in principle, be attacked by other methods. I don't think anyone has ruled out this possibility, in any case. 

Comment: Doubtless one could vandalize Erdos-Selberg type arguments to get, *uniformly*, Chebyshev-type estimates of arbitrary strength, so I would say it is *impossible* to "rule out" this possibility.  But if one found a weak theory of arithmetic where the known Chebyshev-type estimates had a formulation but not the Erdos-Selberg proof, then the result Diamond describes would have more than psychological import.

I believe working in the theory of bounded induction it remains open even to prove the infinitude of the primes.  So people do think about which theory just captures which argument.

Comment: Every circular proof is also a proof of equivalence. That is, the unsatisfying circular proof, using an assumption that ends up depending on the thing to be proved, is also a proof the assumption is equivalent to the conclusion (they both imply each other). The hard part is to extract from the disappointment the bidirection or circle of implication.

Comment: The estimate $\psi(x)=x+O_{\varepsilon}(x^{1/2+\varepsilon})$ implies RH, which implies $\psi(x)=x+O(x^{1/2}\log^2{x})$.  I've always found this rather amusing.

Comment: Given that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational we get that for every rational with $\frac{p}{q} \le \sqrt{2}$ we have $\frac{p}{q} <\frac{p}{q}+\frac{1}{3q^2} <\sqrt{2}$ with something similar from above.

Comment: http://www.tricki.org/article/A_non-trivial_circular_argument_can_often_be_usefully_perturbed_to_a_non-circular_one

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Perhaps an example of the kind of circularity you mention
arises with the self-reference phenomenon that arises in
connection with the [incompleteness
theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems)
and related applications. Specifically, Gödel proved
the fixed-point lemma that for any assertion $\varphi(x)$
in arithmetic, there is a sentence $\psi$ such that PA, or
any sufficiently powerful and expressible theory, proves
that $\psi$ is equivalent to
$\varphi(\ulcorner\psi\urcorner)$. In other words, $\psi$
is equivalent to the statement "$\psi$ has property
$\varphi$." Thus, statements in the language of arithmetic
can refer to themselves, and so self-reference, the stuff
of paradox and nonsense, enters our beautiful number
theory.

One famous example, used by Gödel to prove the first
incompleteness theorem, occurs when $\varphi(x)$ asserts,
"$x$ is the code of a statement having no proof in PA", for
then the resulting fixed point $\psi$ effectively asserts
"this statement is not provable". It follows now that it
cannot be provable, for then it would be a false provable
statement, and so it is true. Thus, it is a true unprovable
statement, establishing the first incompleteness theorem.

A dual version of this, however, exhibits your circularity
property in a stronger way. Namely, let us apply the fixed
point lemma to the formula $p(x)$ asserting "$x$ is the
code of a statement provable in PA." In this case, the
resulting fixed point $\psi$ asserts "this statement IS
provable." Consider now the following theorem of Löb:

**Theorem.**(Löb) If the Peano Axioms (PA) prove the implication (PA proves
$\varphi$)$\to\varphi$, then PA proves $\varphi$
directly.

(And the converse is immediate, so PA proves that (PA
proves $\varphi$)$\to \varphi$ if and only if PA proves
$\varphi$.)

In the case of $\psi$ asserting "$\psi$ is provable," we
have that the hypothesis of Löb's theorem holds, and
so we may make the conclusion that yes, indeed, $\psi$
really is provable! In other words, the statement "this
statement is provable" really is provable, although no
naive argument will establish this.

---

The proof of Löb's theorem is itself a surprising
exercise in circularity, something like the following:

**Theorem.** Santa exists.

Proof. Let $S$ be the statement, "If S holds, then Santa
exists." Now, we claim that $S$ is true. Since it is an
implication, we assume the hypothesis, and argue for the
conclusion. So assume that the hypothesis of S is true;
that is, assume $S$ holds. But then the implication
expressed by $S$ is true. So the conclusion that Santa
exists is also true. So we have shown under the assumption
of the hypothesis of $S$ that the conclusion is true. So we
have established that $S$ holds. Now, by $S$, it follows
that Santa exists. QED

(Those who know the proof of Löb's theorem will agree
that the proof is fundamentally the same as the above,
except that it is fully rigorous nonsense instead of silly
nonsense!)

Comment: Thanks! Löb's theorem is new to me.  Did you you mean to vary the typeface of "S" that once?

Comment: This is a really nice answer Joel.

Comment: David, that different-font S was a typo. Here is a link to Loeb's theorem on Wikipedia: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b's_theorem (watch out for the apostraphe, which somehow causes a problem). And thank you, Adam, I'm glad you like it!

Comment: yudkowsky.net/rational/lobs-theorem 

Comment: Here's another attempt to link the Löb's theorem Wiki article:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Löb%27s_theorem .