# prime powers between n and 2n

Tags: prime-numbers

Is there a result in the spirit of Bertrand-Chebyshev which talks about the existence of prime powers between n and 2n (or 3n or something like that) for n large?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It follows from the prime number theorem that for fixed $k$, provided $n$ is sufficiently large, there is a prime $p$ such that $p^k$ is between $n$ and $2n$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. Yes, it answers the question, and it goes to show the power of the PNT.  

Comment: I wonder if there is an elementary proof of this without using PNT, like Erdős' proof of Bertrand's Postulate?

Answer (score 17):

Actually there is a power of 2. It goes to show the power of binary arithmetic ... : write *2n* in binary and write zeroes after the initial one.

Comment: In other words, if $2^{k - 1}$ is the largest power of 2 less than n, then $n \leq 2^k < 2n$?

Comment: Yes, you said it.

Answer (score 6):

For fixed $k$, the existence of a prime power $p^k$ between $n$ and $2n$ is (asymptotically) equivalent to the existence of a prime $p$ between $m$ and $\sqrt[k]{2} m$ where $m = \sqrt[k]{n}$. Bachraoui gives an elementary proof [here](http://www.m-hikari.com/ijcms-password/ijcms-password13-16-2006/elbachraouiIJCMS13-16-2006.pdf) that there exists a prime between $m$ and $\frac{3}{2} m$ for sufficiently large $m$.

I remember reading on MO that it is known that similar elementary proofs exist for showing the existence of primes between $m$ and $(1 + \epsilon) m$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ and, furthermore, that the existence of these proofs itself depends on the PNT. However, I can't track down where I read this.

Comment: Possibly it is this question you have in mind:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53498/nontrivial-circular-arguments

Comment: Yes, that's the one. 